# How to nest a global macro within a global macro in Stata?

Tags: global, stata, stata-macros

I would like to put a global macro *within* a global macro in a Stata.

For example, `$hello$oneworld`, which is the global macro `$one` inside the macro `$helloworld`.

How do I get a global macro within a global macro?

Answer (score 0):

Advanced manipulation of global macros is covered in [U] 18.3.10 which is bundled with Stata and independently accessible at www.stata.com/manuals/u18.pdf

```
$hello$oneworld
```

is just the contents of `$hello` followed by the contents of `$oneworld`; in either case that is evaluated as empty if the global macro is not defined.

I don't understand what you want to see, but curly braces allow some subtle effects. On the whole the nesting of macro references is easier with local macros, which in general are greatly preferable for almost all purposes.

You perhaps should give examples of precisely what you want to achieve.